# Treemap sorting

Tags: java, treemap

I have this chunk of code:

```
private final static TreeMap<String, UserNotification> USER_NOTIFICATION_MAP = new TreeMap<String, UserNotification>();

//Filling the map using services

String idString = "1";
Iterator it = USER_NOTIFICATION_MAP.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) 
{
    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    idString = pairs.getKey().toString();   
    System.out.println(idString);
}
```

For map with the following pairs:
2 - UserNotification,
3 - UserNotification,
4 - UserNotification,
5 - UserNotification,
6 - UserNotification,
7 - UserNotification,
8 - UserNotification,
9 - UserNotification,
10 - UserNotification

the output from the code is:
10
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

How is that possible, considering the fact that TreeMap sorts all the data by its keys? I suppose that the key with value 10 should be at the end of the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `TreeMap` is sorting based on it's keys *lexicographically* (alphabetically), so anything beginning with a 1 comes before anything starting with a 2 etc.

If you want to sort your map *numerically*, you should be using a `TreeMap<Integer, UserNotification>`

Answer (score 3):

You are using String comparison not Integer. So "10" is before "2".

Comment: Oh, seems to Andrew answered few sec. before me :)

Comment: This was quick, yes! :)

Answer (score 3):

That happens because you're using `String`s in your key set.

Therefore, the `Strings` are sorted by lexicographical order, hence `10` is before `2`.

Use `Integer`s (or `Long`s) to have the intended order.